# Android testing in-app purchases without uploading new apk?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, apk, android-inapp-purchase

I'm trying to test my in-app billing, but I seem to be having a problem. Whenever I try to test it after making changes in android studio, it says "Item not available for purchase".. but if I upload that exact same apk to developer console as an update (app is in beta), it works fine.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to test it, with my actual items, without having to wait the 2-3 hours for the apk to upload every time I make a change?

My versionCode and versionName in build.gradle match the last apk uploaded to developer console

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not do it without uploading apk to at least alpha channel.

[According to documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html):

> In either case, you need to publish your app to Google Play's alpha and beta release channels to manage the users who can make purchases.

Comment: Okay thanks, my app is uploaded to beta, but it's a pain waiting the 3 hours to test the in app purchases every time I make a change.. they should make a change to that system lol!

Comment: @LBJ33 Why you have to do many changes and thus need to reupload app every time. Maybe I'm wrong, but, may your changes only linked to purchases in app, but not actually them. Because as I think you for in app purchases you need to test, that money transaction works, that all. Then if you will something that relates to in app billing, then you can make for example proxy for your purchases and in on test device use this proxy, but in beta use actual purchase system